# Got error at line Glide.with(this).load.imageURL.into(imageURLs). It seems it got error at "(this)"

Tags: java, android

Here is part where my coding got problem. I got error at "this". try to change to context but still got error

```
 public void setAll(String imageURL ,String name, String age, String height, String skin){

        ImageView imageURLs = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.ivpicture);
       // Glide.with(this).load(imageURL).into(imageURLs);
        Glide.with(this).load(imageURL).into(imageURLs) ; //problem here



        TextView names = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
        names.setText(name);


        TextView ages = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tvage);
        ages.setText(age);


        TextView heights = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tvheight);
        heights.setText(height);


        TextView skins = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tvskin);
        skins.setText(skin);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `this` when you are calling Glide from inside another class in this case `AllUsersViewHolder`. You need to pass the context somehow and use that in place of `this`. You can technically get the context from `mView.getContext()`. Regardless of all that, you are using the `ViewHolder` pattern wrong. All the text assigning that you are doing needs to be done in `populateViewHolder` function using `viewHolder.<layout>.setText(text)`. Look at this recycler view [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView) for help